# How to apply CSS in Structural Directive?

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

I was making my own directive Structure Directive what I want is when the value is present in the UI part then this will be telling my directive that i have the value now so make is 
beautiful with CSS ( with the help of `viewContainerRef` from `@angular/core` )

1. what I want is whenever the value is present ***How to apply CSS on Structural Directive*** ?

Here is my code

HTML Part

```
<p *myDirective="type">{{err}}</p>
```

myDirective as Directive Class

Any help would Appreciate.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. `<p class="someClass" *myDirective="type">` Or do you want to have @Input inside structural directive?

Comment: @yurzui I had made my own directive of name **myDirective** I want to apply CSS on this ,Yes I can do with appling `id=" "` on it but is their any possible way to do with TemplateRef Class which is Comming from `@angular` module ?